# Is there any reason not to illegally sell Red Pollen Orbs?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2, xenoblade-2-torna-golden-country

The quest objective for *A Rare Sense of Justice* is to find and destroy 70 green barrels to remove Red Pollen Orbs from circulation. However, despite Red Pollen Orbs being illegal contraband, I noticed I can sell the orbs I find in these barrels for 500g each. Additionally, the quest log only tracks the barrels I've destroyed rather than the orbs I've collected.

Morality aside, is there any reason not to sell any Red Pollen Orbs I find? Will the quest giver notice what I've done?

[image: Rare sense of Justice description]

[image: Option to sell Red Pollen Orbs]

Answer (score 1):

During my playthrough of *Torna - The Golden Country*, I did not find a use for Red Pollen Orbs. There did not seem to be any repercussions for selling them outside of a personal feeling of guilt.